# How to change the node width in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing a shape using `tikzpicture` as follows

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1.7, every node/.style={transform shape}]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5mm, text centered, minimum height=4mm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -]
\node [scale=.9](x1) {};
\coordinate [below of=x1, node distance=1cm] (bx1);
\node [block, below of=x1, node distance=.55cm,scale=.6] (f) {$f_{3n-1}^{(1)}$};
\path[line] (x1) -- (f);
\draw[->] (f) -- (bx1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output of the .tex file for the above line is given by

[image]

My Question: What changes should I make to the code so that `3n-1` is in the body of the box?

I changed the `scale` command, but the output format was not correct.

Edit: I am drawing a picture that its first round is given by

[image]

Comment: You have to increase the `text width` of the node: `text width=3em` for example.

Comment: @Sigur Amazing answer. It works so fine. I want to request you to explain all options of the node as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: If you want that draw, a single down arrow with a node in the middle, you can use simply `\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]\draw[->] (0,0) --node[draw,fill=white]{$f_{3n-1}^{(1)}$} (0,-2cm);\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: **All options** is too much, there are dozens of that. See the TikZ user guide http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: @Sigur Thanks for your useful hint. I want to update my post to see you a part of the picture that I want to draw.

Comment: If you wish you can change `text width=5mm` in the `block` style defined. Or delete that option and let tikz compute the minimal width necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickly solution is to change `text width=5mm` in the `block` style you had defined. Or delete that option and let TikZ determines the minimal width necessary to fit the node text.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond to my questions.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE